# How can I make equal-width items based on the content of items in respective columns?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following layout. The goal is to have the content boxes align and have equal widths with each other vertically, based on their content. The first layout is a desktop page, and the second is how it should look on mobile. I have numbered the boxes to show the desired order.

I've included a JSFiddle with how I've managed to get the desktop view to work, but the problem is that the order is incorrect for the mobile view, due to the HTML structure.

The only ways I can see getting this to work would be to simplify the HTML into 6 direct child li elements, and then assign them widths with CSS, or use JS to programmatically assign the widths. Or, I can create two separate HTML modules, one for desktop and one for mobile, and use CSS to hide/display them.

Those solutions seem over complicated, though. Is there a more elegant solution, which requires less lines of code and time to develop?

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/2sLdpk4e/2/

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

li{
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;
}

.group-item{
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.group-item:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group-item">
        1 Cont
      </div>
      <div class="group-item">
        4 Contentttt
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group-item">
        2 Cont
      </div>
      <div class="group-item">
        5 Content Contentttt
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group-item">
        3 Content Content
      </div>
      <div class="group-item">
        6 Cont
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're probably looking to use something like flexbox to get this effect. See an overview https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @JayBee I tried, please see my demo. I can't use order, because they are grandchild elements, in respect with the flex container.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? It looks like you already have a working solution to do it in your question.

Comment: @TylerH Check Paulie_D's answer for what I consider to be efficient. I'll have to try it out later, but it looks like it may be the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @JordanCarter: can you explain what it is about Paulie's answer that is efficient? Are you looking for brevity of code, or speed of page rendering?

Comment: @halfer Brevity of code. I can see how my use of the word "efficient" could be misleading there. I meant efficient in the sense that it takes less time to develop and edit, so it's an efficient use of time. I edited my original post to hopefully make it more clear to future readers : ).

Comment: @TylerH Hi Tyler, thanks for your edits, however I disagree with the final edit. I was not simply looking for a solution that doesn't add so many wrapper elements. Indeed, I already tried that method, as shown in my code, and couldn't get the ordering the way I wanted. What I wanted was a solution that avoided using JS, assigning CSS widths, creating two separate HTML blocks, or anything else complex like that. I was hoping to find a simple and effective solution, like Paulie's answer. I'd describe it as elegant or straightforward if you don't like practical. I'm not sure why this is closed?

Comment: @JordanCarter The goal of the edit is to remove the off-topic language and make it objectively answerable. It was closed because it was asking for an opinion-based thing: "efficient". If you can rephrase it to more accurately mean what you want while still keeping it *objective* (efficient, clean, verbose, etc. are all *subjective* measurements), please by all means go for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS-Grid can do that without wrapping the items into groups....

```css
body {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  gap: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.group-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-item">
  1 Cont
</div>
<div class="group-item">
  2 Cont
</div>
<div class="group-item">
  3 Content Content
</div>
<div class="group-item">
  4 Contentttt
</div>

<div class="group-item">
  5 Content Contentttt
</div>

<div class="group-item">
  6 Content
</div>
```

For smaller viewports just use a media query and change the display property of the overall wrapper (here I used the `body`) to `display:block` and your items will naturally become a column.

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WNbMpZM)

Comment: This is a good answer.  Ungrouping the elements will solve the problems you're having the "grandchild" components.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. Have a wonderful day.